# Why is Assert not throwing an exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The following code extracts and prints all the menu options on a site. The options are stored in a List. That is working fine.

BUT I want it to throw an assert exception if the options contained in the list does not contain "Foruma". Nothing is happening and my options do not contain "Foruma". Here is the main portion of my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.sojicity.com");
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("main-menu"));

List<WebElement> menuOptions = mainMenu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

System.out.println(menuOptions.size() + " menu options found!");

String optText;

// this portion just lists off all the found menu options
for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.size(); i++) {
    optText = menuOptions.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(optText);
}

String toFind = "Forums";

assert menuOptions.contains(toFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use assertTrue . Also, make a static import of Assert.assertTrue :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue; 

assertTrue(menuOptions.contains(toFind));
```